# Vagrant acesso compartilhado entre equipe

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

**Cenário:**

- Duas máquinas (A e B), ambas na mesma rede local e com vagrant e virtualbox instalado. Uma é Windows e outra é mac
- Na máquina A tenho um uma box homestead (laravel/homestead) com todo meu ambisnte.

**Problema**

Preciso que a máquina B acesse as pastas e URL da box da máquina A. Segue o que eu já tentei fazer e que não me atende:

- vagrant share --ssh. Não me atende por que cai depois de uma hora
- vagrant package e publicar o ambiente.

  - Não me atende por que não quero que os outros desenvolvedores tenham que subir cada um uma box em suas próprias máquinas
- Copiar o vagrantfile ou seja o ambiente para as outras máquinas e dar um vagrant up.

  - Não me atende pelo motivo citado acima

Abaixo segue detalhadamente o que eu já fiz .

**Solução - SHARE --SSH**

Executando esses 3 comandos conforme documentação eu consegui atingir o objetivo:

- Share
- connect
- [ssh](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/share.html#_ssh)

Em sumo:

Máquina A:

```
vagrant login
vagrant share --ssh
```

Máquina B:

```
vagrant connect --ssh
```

Deu tudo certo. Mas essa solução não me atende porque a conexão cai depois de uma hora conforme documentação: [security share](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/security.html#_disable_http)

**Solução - Package  ou copiar ambiente Vagrantfile**

As soluções atráves da publicaçao de box na hashicorp

```
vagrant package
```

ou copiando o ambiente (vagrantfile) para depois dar um

```
vagrant up # na máquina B
```

Também não me atendem.

**Sugestões**

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para me ajudar?

Gostaria de deixar a máquina A sempre ligada para que a máquina B, C ou D dos desenvolvedores acessem ela através de uma IP ou algo do gênero.

Gostaria de saber se posso fazer isso através Private_network ou Public_network do vagrantfile?

Alguém que conhece esses recursos e que já tenha feito algo similar pode me ajudar, por favor.

Valeu pessoal.

Answer (score 0):

Então, é só usar uma rede privada ("private_network") e uma chave pública para acesso via SSH. Para isso, você escreveria no Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "58.147.128.0"
```

Na máquina que será acessada, é necessário adicionar a chave pública das máquinas que irão acessá-la no arquivo ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Isso é uma forma de autenticação, você poderia também usar um usuário e senha, mas acho o uso da chave pública mais seguro por não expor credenciais. Algumas formas de configurar o acesso remoto a um servidor linux estão nesse [artigo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server).